# definition of the genus of a global field of positive characteristic

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Suppose that $K$ is a function field in one variable over a finite field $k$. Can anyone direct me to a resource that explains the definition of the genus of $K$?

Comment: Finiteness of the field has nothing to do with the case. I’m not up on modern literature, but any text on algebraic curves should do you fine.